# Is there a way to change the name format of copied objects with bpy?

Tags: python, objects

I'm using bpy.

By copying `Cube` repeatedly, I get `Cube.001` to `Cube.999`, and then `Cube.1000` to `Cube.9999`, and then `Cube.10000` to `Cube.99999`, etc.

Is there a way to change the name format of copied objects with bpy, so that I can get `Cube.00001` to `Cube.99999`?

The motivation is that objects in `bpy.data.objects[]` are ordered by names.
With `Cube.001` to `Cube.999`, the indexes are the suffixes.
However, when I get `Cube.1000`, it is inserted between `Cube.100` and `Cube.101` and the indexes of `Cube.101` to `Cube.999` are all offset by 1.

Comment: How are you copying them?  Why not rename on copy? Re motivationt an object named "Bozo" will also muck up indices?